# SIM micro SD Adapter

Tags: laptop, wireless, mobile-phone, microsd

**Is there a** (definitely non-scam ;) ) **SIM to SD card adapter, microSD in my case**, to use your cellular data on your laptop/pc **?**

*Because I can’t find one.* Best, small, of course.

Answer (score 3):

You can't just add a SIM card. **You need a modem** on your laptop that can send and receive the RF cell signals. Laptops that come with a SIM slot, will have an extra slot for a WWAN card inside that will perform this function.

WWAN (Wireless Wide Area Network) cards look and operate similarly to WLAN (Wireless Local Area Network), or WiFi+Bluetooth cards, and often fit in the same slots. The main difference between the two is the frequency that they operate on, but the protocols that they use are also different.

Sometimes you can get away with just a WWAN card and the antennas, but you usually also need a SIM card slot. If your laptop doesn't have a WWAN slot inside, then you can purchase a [USB cellular modem](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0069RXK9G), but these days your carrier will try to sell you a standalone hotspot instead. If you already have a cellphone account, you can often get a hotspot for free and pay an additional amount per month as if you were adding an extra phone line.